# How many processes will be created by the C program below?

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child

Can you give a explanation along with the answer. I'm having some issue with identifying the correct no of processes that have being created by these system calls.

I think there will be 8 processes created.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Here comes the date. \n");    
    printf("Here it is. \n");

    fork();    
    fork();    
    fork();

    execl("/bin/date", "date", 0); //Line A

    printf("That was the date. \n"); //Line B    
    printf("Program will exit now. \n"); //Line C    
}
```

Comment: Note that the final two `print()` function calls will not be executed  (called) unless the `execl()` call fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent creates three children, one on each `fork()`, but first children only executes two `fork()` calls (it starts after the first fork), second creates a single new child (the last fork) and last creates none (starts after the last fork)
from the first children, two more (the first creating another child and the second none) so in total we have three processes, two, one and one, adding to 7 subprocesses created, plus the first one, a total of eight.  You will see the first two lines of output (as no `fork()` has yet been issued) then eight times the date command executed once per parent, children and grandchildren, and the last two lines are not output because always there's an `execv(2)` call that never returns (only returns if the call to `date` command fails)

```
parent
 |
 + fork() -> cld1
 |            |
 |            + fork() -> cld11
 |            |            |
 |            |            + fork() -> cld111
 |            |            |           |
 |            |            |           +execv(date)
 |            |            |
 |            |            + execv(date)
 |            |   
 |            + fork() -> cld12
 |            |            |
 |            |            + execv(date)
 |            |
 |            + execv(date)
 |
 + fork() -> cld2
 |            |
 |            + fork() -> cld21
 |            |            |
 |            |            + execv(date)
 |            |
 |            + execv(date)
 |
 + fork() -> cld3
 |            |
 |            + execv(date)
 |
 + execv(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shown creates seven processes. When the code starts, there is already a process executing the program. Then `fork` creates one more, so there are two.

Then those two processes execute `fork`, each creating one more process, so there are four.

Then those four processes execute `fork`, each creating one more process, so there are eight.

Thus seven new processes are created.

The `execl` does not create a new process; it just changes what program the process is executing.

Comment: @EricPostpichil will there be a single parent or will every fork call have a parent is self ? can you clarify that.

Comment: @Zakey.M.S.M.A: When a process calls `fork`, it becomes the parent of the child process that is created.